# Removing 32 Characters long string from Product Image paths in Magento

Tags: magento, seo

The default product image paths have the following structure in Magento:
http://www.domainname.com/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/9df61e8b45590e35df96d9f179ca0b11/u/n/product-name.png

We know the 32 characters long string is generated based on a lot of factors like store_id, attributes, watermark etc, however does it's presence affects the SEO of images in Google? Additionally, how do we change the image generating Magento file so that the hash is removed alltogether from the path.

Answer (score 0):

remove magento/media/catalog/product/cache folder then refresh cache
refresh "Flush Catalog Images Cache", refresh cache and storage  in cache management in admin panel then check it.

Comment: Deleting the image and Megnto cache would not be helpful as the next time the catalog images are generated the hash would still be present in the image file names.  I am looking at a solution where the hash gets removed from the image fle paths all-together.